# How do I merge multiple excel files to a single excel file

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

So I was trying to make an excel sheet aggregator. In my line of work we get people who send us a bunch of individual excel files that are all related each with only 1 sheet used.

I was following to some degree [this previous post's ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808368/c-sharp-how-to-copy-a-single-excel-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-another). But upon doing so, some of the excel sheets I copied were coming up blank. Only certain ones. I have no idea why some are blank and others are fine.

Here is the code I use to open and copy the excel files

```
         OpenFileDialog browse = new OpenFileDialog();
            browse.Multiselect = true;
            DialogResult result = browse.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)

                try //try to open it. If its a proper excel file
                {   
                    excel = new Excel.Application();
                    excel.Workbooks.Add("");
                    finalized = excel.Workbooks[1];
                    excel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
                    for(int i=0; i< browse.FileNames.Length; i++)
                    {
                        excel.Workbooks.Add(browse.FileNames[i]);
                    }
                    //skip the first workbook as it is the finalized one
                    //also note everything in excel starts at 1 and not 0
                    for(int i=2; i<excel.Workbooks.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int count = excel.Workbooks[i].Worksheets.Count;
                        excel.Workbooks[i].Activate();
                        for (int j = 1; j < count; j++)
                        {

                            Excel._Worksheet pastee = (Excel._Worksheet)excel.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
                            Excel._Worksheet sheet = (Excel._Worksheet)finalized.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                            //Excel._Worksheet sheet = finalized.Sheets[1];
                            pastee.Copy(Before: sheet);


                        }//end of for j
                    }//end of for i
                }//end of try
```

Here is the code I use to save the excel file

```
            SaveFileDialog browse = new SaveFileDialog();
            browse.Title = "Save as Excel";
            browse.Filter = "Excel workbook | *.xlsx";
            DialogResult result = browse.ShowDialog();

            finalized.SaveAs(browse.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault);

            MessageBox.Show("Success", "Message");
            //unlock the file
            Global.releaseComObjects(finalized, excel);
```

Comment: What do you want to do actually? You want to copy the excel files which are not blank or are the excel files getting while you are copying? @Alexander Ryan Baggett

Comment: As I tried to explain in the description. I want to open multiple excel files. Copy every sheet from those files into 1 single new excel file.

Comment: The excel sheets on the files I am opening are not blank.

Comment: Actually found a freely available add-in for that which works great: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two excel files into one with their sheet names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568613/how-to-merge-two-excel-files-into-one-with-their-sheet-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your inner loop you add a new worksheet to your 'finalized' workbook ('sheet') AND copy a worksheet before it for every source sheet. So every 'sheet' created by your `Add` command will be empty as in fact you create two sheets for each source sheet. Another problem is, that - as you mentioned - arrays in excel are 1-based; so you have to loop until `j <= count` not `j < count`.

So I think that code would work better:

```
Excel.Worksheet dummy = finalized.Worksheets[1];

for (int i = 2; i <= excel.Workbooks.Count; i++)
{
    int count = excel.Workbooks[i].Worksheets.Count;

    for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++)
    {
        Excel._Worksheet pastee = (Excel._Worksheet)excel.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
        pastee.Copy(dummy);
    }
}

dummy.Delete();
```

Comment: I tried it and it seems to copy text only - without any style/fonts/colors etc. could be issue with Excel.Interop version, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to merge worksheets into one is through a third part component called Spire.Xls. It’s a standalone .NET component.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Spire.Xls;
using System.Data;


namespace Spire.XLS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        //load the first workbook
        workbook.LoadFromFile(@"merge1.xlsx");
        //load the second workbook
        Workbook workbook2 = new Workbook();
        workbook2.LoadFromFile(@"merge2.xlsx");

        //import the second workbook's worksheet into the first workbook using a datatable
        Worksheet sheet2 = workbook2.Worksheets[0];
        DataTable dataTable = sheet2.ExportDataTable();
        Worksheet sheet1 = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        sheet1.InsertDataTable(dataTable, false, sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1);


        //save the workbook
        workbook.SaveToFile("result.xlsx");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without purchasing Spire.Xls the limitation is 3 pages