# Appending Memorystream to existing Memorystream

Tags: c#

Im having trouble appending the data in a **MemoryStream** to other **Memorystream** allready created an **full of data**.
I'm doing this to create an excel from two different sources.

First I create the father memorystream:

```
MemoryStream obj_stream = new MemoryStream(100000000);
var tempFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".xls");
obj_stream.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(tempFile), 0, File.ReadAllBytes(tempFile).Length);
File.Delete(tempFile);
```

Then I create the son memorystream from a compositeLink.ExportToXls

```
compositeLink.CreatePageForEachLink();
compositeLink.PrintingSystemBase.XlSheetCreated += PrintingSystemBase_XlSheetCreated;

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(100000000))
{
    compositeLink.ExportToXls(stream, new XlsExportOptions() { ExportMode = XlsExportMode.SingleFilePageByPage });
    obj_stream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
}
```

Finally I write the stream to a Page.Response

```
if (Page == null || Page.Response == null)
    return;
string disposition = saveAsFile ? "attachment" : "inline";
Page.Response.Clear();
Page.Response.Buffer = false;
Page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", string.Format("application/{0}", fileFormat));
Page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
Page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("{0}; filename={1}.{2}", disposition, fileName, fileFormat));
Page.Response.BinaryWrite(obj_stream.ToArray());
Page.Response.End();
```

What is happening I believe is that either one or the other gets overwritten by the other, depending on which one I do the "nameOfTheStream".write()

Comment: You can't combine two spreadsheets by just concatenating two `.xls` files together.

Comment: You have to consider file headers etc. If You're trying to concat two xls files, consider populating a third (new) xls file with the values of the two previous ones.

Comment: How do I merge multiple excel files into one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285615/how-do-i-merge-multiple-excel-files-to-a-single-excel-file

Answer (score 0):

The second time time you write to `obj_stream`, do not start writing from 0 index (specified in second parameter of Write method) again. There is some data in there already.

```
obj_stream.Write(stream.ToArray(), obj_stream.ToArray().Length, stream.ToArray().Length);
```

Method details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.write?view=netframework-4.7.2).