# Multiple worksheets using flat file destination in ssis

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am trying to create multiple worksheets in excel using ssis. I am using flat file destination for creating the excel file by changing the file extension to xls. I can successfully create multiple excel files but what i am looking to do is to create multiple excel files with multiple worksheets. Can anyone suggest a simple workaround for that.
Thanks

Comment: This is not a duplicate for the link you provided as I am looking to create multiple worksheets for flat file destination not by using the excel destination.

Comment: Oh, ok.   In that case I will answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Excel connection Manager / Excel Destination to achieve that, also you may need to utilize from Execute SQL Task to create Excel Worksheets if you cannot do that manually:

- [SSIS: Dynamically Generate Excel Table/Sheet](https://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/)
- [Export SQL Server Data to Multiple Excel Worksheets with Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5178/export-sql-server-data-to-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-integration-services/)
- [SSIS - SQL to Excel](https://oakdome.com/programming/SSIS_DataTransform.php)
- [Export SQL Server Data to Multiple Excel Worksheets using SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5324/export-sql-server-data-to-multiple-excel-worksheets-using-sql-server-integration-services/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create multiple worksheets using the Flat File Destination.   This can only be done using the Excel Destination, using the technique shown in the linked question above.

Comment: But is it a way that we can get data from 2 different flat file destination and then merge them into a single file? while using the flat file with a .xls extension.

Comment: It can't be done as part of the dataflow, but you can run a script task after all the files are created and programmatically merge the files.   It won't be simple.   Here is a Q/A that can get you started:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285615/how-do-i-merge-multiple-excel-files-to-a-single-excel-file

Comment: As of now I am getting all the files created by using 2 different flat file destination and I am getting all the files in the same folder as excel files but the problem is that they are separate files. I am looking to merge both the files in a way that both of these would be worksheets in a single excel file.

Comment: I understand that, and my comment above addresses that.

Comment: The link you provided is showing the way of merging the excel worksheets however I am using flat files so I dont think this is the way to do it.

Comment: It's a necessary step.  You have to convert your flat files to Excel files, which you are doing by changing the extension.   Then you follow the link to merge the excel files into one file with multiple worksheets.

Comment: I am looking to get all these worksheets in a loop where there will be multiple excel files created with multiple worksheets init. Thanks